# How to get msmq message "received" when queue is set to Authenticated?

Tags: wcf, msmq, msmq-wcf

I'm using WCF 4.0 and the service is hosted in IIS (WAS), with a net.msmq address. I'm starting out by simply sending an int through a method. In my web.config I have the following. Note- I can't hook to AD because of other restrictions. Even without AD, a person should still be able to use local accounts for security.

```
<binding name="Q" useActiveDirectory="false" useMsmqTracing="true">
  <security mode="None">
    <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="WindowsDomain" 
               msmqProtectionLevel="None" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

I have Msmq End2End events logged and it shows that eventIDs 1 and 5 are recorded, but **no event for EventID 2 ("Message Received")**.

If I uncheck "Authenicated" in the queue properties, the event is logged - But that's not desirable, as then there's no security :) So that's why I'm posting out to you folks.

There's a local private queue set up, and journaling is enabled. Neither of these have a message in them - I made sure to f5 for fresh results too. I have the security set to the iis app pool user having full control, as well as giving Network Service read/peek. I've also tried everyone full control, temporarily, but that didn't help either. I also tried a non-transactional queue but that didn't help either.

The message doesn't show up in the Journal, and there are no errors logged, but maybe I'm not looking in the right spot. Any pointers on that would be helpful too.